# MS Access Date filter between from user

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a MS access query which gets date from users and selects values based on it

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1    
WHERE ((DateValue([Table1].[Date_col]) 
Between "#"&[Forms]![Frm1]![Date1]&"#" 
and "#"&[Forms]![Frm1]![Date2]&"#"))
```

I'm getting empty output ?

Any idea friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting the table's column to a `DateValue` (i.e. a number) and the others you are converting into strings with a leading and trailing `#`

Either convert them all to dates:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1    
WHERE CVDate([Table1].[Date_col]) 
    BETWEEN CVDate([Forms]![Frm1]![Date1]) 
    AND CVDate([Forms]![Frm1]![Date2])
```

or better still if they are already dates, just leave them:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1    
WHERE [Table1].[Date_col]
    BETWEEN [Forms]![Frm1]![Date1]
    AND [Forms]![Frm1]![Date2]
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But Date_Col is of date with time stamp format (01/01/2011 19.12) like this. how can i achieve this